# MySQL Copy a string between fields if the target field is empty

Tags: mysql, sql, string, sql-update, where-clause

I'm working with a WordPress database where some of the `post_title` fields are empty. I need to fill these with a string from the field `post_content`. The string is located between two tags: `<strong>Text string</strong>`.

I can successfully find and copy the strings using:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` 
SET `post_title` = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`post_content`, '<strong>', -1), '</strong>', 1)
FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE `post_title` = ''
```

However, `WHERE post_title = ''` doesn't work. This overwrites all `post_title` fields instead of only the empty fields.

I can select the empty `post_title` fields using:

```
SELECT `post_title` FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_title` = ''
```

but I'm not sure how to combine these two actions – or if this the right way to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not valid MySQL syntax, and should error. MySQL does not want a `from` clause in `update`  statements, so that should be:

```
update `wp_posts` 
set `post_title` = substring_index(substring_index(`post_content`, '<strong>', -1), '</strong>', 1)
where `post_title` = ''
```

Side note: you might also want to check if `post_title` is `null` (which is a different thing that the empty string):

```
where `post_title` = '' or `post_title` is null
```

Answer (score 0):

> WHERE post_title = '' doesn't work. This overwrites all post_title fields instead of only the empty fields.

This is simply not true.  However, your query is not valid MySQL syntax.  The correct query would be:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` 
    SET `post_title` = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`post_content`, '<strong>', -1), '</strong>', 1)
    WHERE `post_title` = '';
```

MySQL doesn't support a `FROM` clause in the `UPDATE`.  Perhaps what got executed was simply the first two line of the query.

Answer (score 0):

You code is not valid and check for NULL Values must be

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` 
SET `post_title` = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`post_content`, '<strong>', -1), '</strong>', 1)
WHERE `post_title` IS  NULL
```